# ASP.NET and Python Communication

Tags: python, asp.net

I am trying to send a message from an asp.net website to a python file running on a raspberry pi.  If this is the code on for the python on the pi

```py
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8089))
serversocket.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(64)
    if len(buf) > 0:
    print buf
    break
```

I just need some help getting started.  Assuming I know the external and internal ip address of the Raspberry Pi that is running the Python code, how would I get started with the code using ASP.NET?

Would I use `socket.io` or something else?  What is the best idea or method to communicate between an ASP.NET website and Python?  I know the question is very general but I just need some help to get started in the right direction.

Comment: If the Python server is listening directly on a socket (and not using some protocol such as HTTP or something) then I imagine directly connecting on a socket from .NET would be the way to go.  Did you try?

Comment: Why you using socket ? Try `wsgiref`, is very basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edit ) Improved ASP.NET CODE:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.107", 8012);

    // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
    Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello There");

    // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
    //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    // Receive the TcpServer.response.

    // Buffer to store the response bytes.
    data = new Byte[256];

    // String to store the response ASCII representation.
    String responseData = String.Empty;

    // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
    Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
    Response.Write(responseData);

    // Close everything.
    stream.Close();
    client.Close();
    }
}
```

Is working and what I am using for now. Is there a better option?  Thank you for the replys.  :)